# Flutter: Remove spacing above keyboard

Tags: ios, flutter, keyboard

was wondering if anyone can help me remove the spacing above the keyboard? I have resizeToAvoidBottomInset and resizeToAvoidBottomPadding set to false in my scaffold and I do not have a scaffold in a scaffold. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: can you share the code please?

Answer (score 0):

Use this line in Scaffold

```
resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false
```